# Parameterless constructor validation. Java

Tags: java, methods

How can I check if there is a parameterless constructor in a class?

I tried:

```
        if (classToCheck.getConstructor() != null) {
            //Yes, there is one.
        } else {
            //No, there isn't one.
        }
```

But `classToCheck.getConstructor()` always returns true.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit.

```
    private boolean hasNoArgConstructor(Class classToCheck) {
    try {

        if (classToCheck.getConstructor() != null) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }

    return false;
}
```

So, the main idea of a method is to get true if there is a constructor in a class that takes no arguments.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Also note that `getConstructor` will never return null: it either returns a constructor *or* throws a `NoSuchMethodException`.

Comment: I'm taking care of NoSuchMethodException in an actual code. Example above is simplified just to understand logic.

Comment: doesn't this  `classToCheck.getConstructor()` return default constructor?

Comment: Well, if `getConstructor()` completes *normally* (i.e. doesn't throw an exception), then it exists.

Comment: @David: yes, that's why I'm asking for a [mre]: your "simplified" code is not sufficient to show your problem. It should be very simple for you to construct a simple example demonstrating the problem with a tiny main method and a second class that shows the issue.

Comment: But `NoSuchMethodException` is exactly what is thrown if you query a constructor that isn't there. Whatever you do to "take care" of it, it's not correct - it's exactly the else case you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just remember that if you dont write any explicit constructor , the compiler will give you a no args constructor implicitly .**

So : class without any constructor ==> become a class with one no argument constructor after compilation.

you can use this code :

```
if(Arrays.stream(classToCheck.class.getConstructors()).filter(constructor -> constructor.getParameterCount() == 0).count() == 1 )
    System.out.println("exists");
else 
    System.out.println("not exists");
```

**Just dont forget that getConstructors() looks just for the public constructors !**

Comment: Or just `Stream.of(BaseProductImport.class.getConstructors()).anyMatch(c -> c.getParameterCount() == 1)`.